# Linker replacing symbolic references with memory addresses?

Tags: c++, memory, linker

From http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html I found this

> C/C++ code is typically compiled to an object file then multiple object files are linked together to product a usable artifact such as an executable or dll. During the linking phase symbolic references in each object file are replaced with an actual memory address relative to the final executable.

How is it possible to determine the relative Memory addresses during linking, if the OS running the executable is the one who is responsible for allocating Memory during Runtime and this Memory gets allocated whereever there is free Memory space (My understanding of how things work).

Comment: The linker outputs relative addresses, the OS turns them into absolute ones when it loads the program.

Comment: So addresses of all variables and objects used and defined inside a program have a fixed relationship to the starting address of the program when it is executed? Implying that if I the OS loading the program have enough Memory but not exactly there at the relative addresses the program won't run?

Comment: "not exactly there at the relative addresses" doesn't make sense. The program doesn't load at a relative address. The OS finds room in its address space for the program, loads it there and then fixes up the addresses. Bear in mind that modern operating systems use a virtualised address space so every process has more or less all of memory to be loaded into.

Comment: A contigious space in the Memory then? so either the whole program fits in a conitigous space or no space at all?Sorry about ignorance, but I work on it every now and then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  memory addresses are *relative to the final executable* -- they are not absolute, that would be impossible to determine during linking.

When an executable is run in Windows, it is granted by the operating system a *virtual memory space* or *virtual address space* of fixed size, usually 4GB on 32-bit OSs. Each process has its own virtual space where it can read and write data to/from memory. Then, the executable and any dependencies are  written to this space, so their location is now known and within the VAS. Now, upon execution, the operating system will take the relative addresses provided by the linker and translate them to absolute addresses. These are determined by the location of the executable in the virtual memory space.

Comment: I got that part, but my question remains. Please refer to my comment on the question itself

Comment: Edited,  although I'm not quite sure what youre asking exactly. The operating system determines the addresses which it includes in the memory space it provides to the program, and it uses that range of addresses to determine where to resolve each relative address to.